# displaying full screen white activity indicator screen in objective-c that hides only after all tasks are completed

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i display a full screen activity indicator in my ios objective-c app when a view controller is loading. in the view controller, there are more that one processes i.e. tasks running. I want to display this activity indicator to cover the whole screen before the view controller loads and hide the activity indicator only after all processes and tasks are complete?

Comment: please make your question more specific, and show us what you've tried so far. are you asking *how* to detect when multiple tasks are complete? (still v. broad) or are you asking how to *display* a full screen view controller that blocks user input? although I suspect that both of these questions have numerous answers all over SO anyway.

Comment: the two are my questions